# Armour and shields in Aspect based combat. Fate Core

Tags: fate-core, equipment, aspects

**Short Version:
What is the correct way to balance a PC having a shield that gives the player additional stress boxes to use. Should this require a stunt or a fate point or use another balancing mechanic.**

Long Version:

I am creating a fantasy game using Fate and found that the lack of weapon differentiation a little too abstract for my taste. Being familiar with D&D and Savage Worlds I immediately set about using the damage and armour modifier rules, but the more I think about it, the more I don't like this approach.

I feel that using an Aspect approach encourages much more flavoursome character creation as players think about their weapon not as a bunch of stats, but rather a character with unique abilities and characteristics. Especially if each weapon is giving a trouble. Imagine "Huge Axe of Doom: - Aspect - Like a knife through butter. Trouble - Hard not to destroy the whole room." This is much more interesting than a +3 modifier.

I'm a bit stuck when it comes to armour and shields however.

I like the idea of giving armour and shields some sort of trouble, "I creak too much to sneak", "I can only see forward" - but for the user of that armour it seems a bit of a kill joy if they need to invoke the "positive" aspect to get the benefit of this equipment each time they are hit by the Orc.

I could have armour and shields simply have stress boxes and a consequence box. A player can elect to have the armour take the damage rather than the character. This approach seems simple enough, but having never run the game I'm unsure what long term effect this will have. Will people with armour be at a huge advantage? I don't for example want a PC with a two handed sword to be a huge disadvantage to his buddy with a sword and shield.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Have you seen the [Fate toolkit entries](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/weapons-and-armor-alternatives) (or Atomic Robo "hardware" rules) on this subject? This'll likely get closed unless it can be narrowed down to the kind of question that can actually have something like a single correct answer, at least based on expertise. Currently it isn't that, and whilst an excellent inquiry, is best served by open back-and-forth discussion which the Stack Exchange's Q&A system doesn't attempt to support.

Comment: Once you have 20+ rep, feel free to join the [chat] where we can talk about this stuff informally and maybe even help workshop the question a bit.

Comment: in the extra section, there's a paragraph about armors and weapons values, might pique your interest.